# MySQL remote connect with JasperStudio

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I'm trying to establish a connection with *Jaspersoft Studio* to a *MySQL* database.

*Jaspersoft Studio* on (Windows 8) and *MySQL* is running on a virtual machine with *openSUSE* on the same hardware.

```
jdbc:mysql://192.168.178.27:3306/icinga (User and pw are given and correct)
The Error: javaSQLException Access denied for user 'icinga@MyPC.frist.box'
```

Because I don't have a bind-address line in my /etc/my.cnf I think the database is ready for remote access.

I can access the database with `192.168.178.27/phpMyAdmin` and the login data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are connecting from a 'remote' host, are you sure that you have the user "icinga" granted rights to connecting from other hosts than local?
It's correct that you can use phpmyadmin, because that's running on the same machine as the databases server and is interpreted by the database server as 'localhost'.